# Convert categorial variables into numeric using scikit-learn's LabelEncoder

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to convert categorical variables into numeric variables using scikit-learn's LabelEncoder:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
var_mod = ['Gender', 'Married', 'Dependents', 'Education', 'Self_Employed', 'Property_Area', 'Loan_Status']
le = LabelEncoder()
for i in var_mod:
    data_train[i] = le.fit_transform(data_train[i])
data_train.dtypes
```

I am running this in Jupyter using Python 3.6.4. It is giving me the following python error:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

I have tried using different methods and permutations (fit vs fit_transform) but I'm still getting the same Python error.

These are the dtypes of my dataframe:

```
Loan_ID               object
Gender                 int64
Married                int64
Dependents            object
Education             object
Self_Employed         object
ApplicantIncome        int64
CoapplicantIncome    float64
LoanAmount           float64
Loan_Amount_Term     float64
Credit_History       float64
Property_Area         object
Loan_Status           object
LoanAmount_log       float64
TotalIncome          float64
TotalIncome_log      float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: One of your columns of type `object` has mixed object types (they're not all strings)... found out which one it is (maybe by just putting a `print(i)` at the start of your loopso you know where it's breaking... and then do a `data_train[i].map(type).value_counts()` to see what the distribution is... and then work out how you want to handle that scenario... (maybe force the column to be all strings first etc...)

Comment: For `Gender` and alike type is already int64, so probably no encoding is required. Btw. you can do label encoding and dummification within pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html and for me it is much better option than sklearn.

Comment: @JonClements you were absolutely right! It was breaking at 'Dependents' so I used `data_train['Dependents'].replace()` to convert them all into integers. Thank you very much!